# Why do you need to give an enum an identifier?

Tags: c, enums

The code

```
enum MyEnum
{
    TEST = 0
} ;

void main(void)
{
    printf("%x", TEST);
}
```

and

```
enum
{
    TEST = 0
} ;

void main(void)
{
    printf("%x", TEST);
}
```

both compile and run the exact same, so what is the purpose of giving an enum an identifier?

Answer (score 2):

Another answer, in addition to those already entered, is that modern compilers can warn if you are using an `enum` in a suspicious way. These warnings are only available if you refer to the `enum` using its type name.

For example, suppose I have

```
enum MyEnum {FOO, BAR};
enum MyEnum x = ...;
//...
switch (x)
  {
  case FOO: //...
     break;
  }
```

The compiler knows that there are two legitimate values for `x` -- `FOO` and `BAR`, and I've only handled one of them in the `switch`. This is likely to be a mistake.

Had I declared `x` as an `int` the code would still have compiled. But the compiler has no way of knowing what the legitimate values of `x` are, and can't warn if I've missed one in my `switch`.

Broadly, the more information you give the compiler about the structure of your data, the better a job it can do of warning you if you might have made errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `enum` is a type if you give it a name, so you can use it in a `struct`, as a variable or as an argument, as in:

```
void example(enum MyEnum input);
```

Without the name it's just a bunch of constants.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a scenario where you are developing some state machine. People more popularly prefer `typedef` with enum to create a user-defined data type.

```
typedef enum myEnum
{
    TEST = 0,
    INIT,
    APP,
    MAINT,
    SUSPEND,
    UPGRADE,
    //
    MAX_STATES
} stateType;

struct application {
    uint64_t ticks;
    uint16_t port;
    //
    stateType stateVal; 
};

int main(void)
{
    struct application app;
    app.stateVal = INIT;
    printf("%x", app.stateVal);
    app.stateVal = 0x64; // This is going to generate a warning! So that you can not assign value with incompatible data type
    // Some code
    //
    //
    return 0; //EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This has allowed you to defined a data type which would let you used values of your choice and context. Without this, you can still use the anonymous `enum` but that would just be a set of constant numbers with no specific purpose to server.

The benefit of such an implementation is if you use a C++ compiler to compile a C source, and when you assign `app.stateVal` with a value which is not part of the `stateType` enum, it will generate a warning asking you to assign a correct (compatible) value.

Comment: Except that you cannot make GCC warn about this :'D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: `-Wall` would warn about this, right?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Oh it doesn't. Thanks for pointing it out. It nly warns if I compile the code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Nope, `gcc enum.c -Wall -Wextra -Wenum-compare -Wswitch-enum -std=c18 -pedantic-errors`